# Kotlin summing with groupingBy and aggregate

Tags: kotlin

tl/dr: How would Kotlin use groupingBy and aggregate to get a Sequence of (key, number) pairs to sum to a map of counts?

I have 30gb of csv files which are a breeze to read and parse.

```
File("data").walk().filter { it.isFile }.flatMap { file ->
    println(file.toString())
    file.inputStream().bufferedReader().lineSequence()
}. // now I have lines
```

Each line is "key,extraStuff,matchCount"

```
.map { line ->
    val (key, stuff, matchCount) = line.split(",")
    Triple(key, stuff, matchCount.toInt())
}.
```

and I can filter on the "stuff" which is good because lots gets dropped -- yay lazy Sequences.  (code omitted)

But then I need a lazy way to get a final Map(key:String to count:Int).

I *think* I should be using groupingBy and aggregate, because `eachCount()` would just count rows, not sum up matchCount, and groupingBy is lazy whereas groupBy isn't, but we have reached the end of my knowledge.

```
.groupingBy { (key, _, _) ->
    key
}.aggregate { (key, _, matchCount) ->
    ??? something with matchCount ???
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Grouping.fold` extension instead of `Grouping.aggregate`. It would be more suitable for summing grouped entries by a particular property:

```
triples
    .groupingBy { (key, _, _) -> key }
    .fold(0) { acc, (_, _, matchCount) -> acc + matchCount }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function with four parameters to [`aggregate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/aggregate.html):

> @param `operation`: function is invoked on each element with the following parameters:
>
> - `key`: the key of the group this element belongs to;
> - `accumulator`: the current value of the accumulator of the group, can be `null` if it's the first `element` encountered in the group;
> - `element`: the element from the source being aggregated;
> - `first`: indicates whether it's the first `element` encountered in the group.

Of them, you need `accumulator` and `element` (which you can destructure). The code would be:

```
.groupingBy { (key, _, _) -> key }
.aggregate { _, acc: Int?, (_, _, matchCount), _ ->
    (acc ?: 0) + matchCount 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem today and, like one of Kotlin's tutorials, I finally solved it. The code is as follows:
(kt sample:https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/02_BlockingRequest)

```
 In the initial list each user is present several times, once for each
 repository he or she contributed to.
 Merge duplications: each user should be present only once in the resulting list
 with the total value of contributions for all the repositories.
 Users should be sorted in a descending order by their contributions.

 The corresponding test can be found in test/tasks/AggregationKtTest.kt.
 You can use 'Navigate | Test' menu action (note the shortcut) to navigate to the test.
*/
fun List<User>.aggregate(): List<User> = this.groupBy { it.login }.map { (login, contributions) ->
    User(login, contributions.sumOf { it.contributions })
}.sortedByDescending { it.contributions }
//or
fun List<User>.aggregate2(): List<User> = this.groupingBy { it.login }.aggregate<User, String, User>{ key, accumulator, element, _ ->
    User(key, (accumulator?.contributions?:0)+element.contributions)
}.map { (_, v)-> v}.sortedByDescending { it.contributions }
```